# Are there other hashing functions in PHP?

Tags: php, hash

I know there are MD5 and SHA1 hashing functions in PHP, but are there any others?

Comment: [hash_algos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
<?php
print_r(hash_algos());
?>
```

This prints a list of all available hashing-algorithms that are available on your system. Chose one and provide it as the first parameter to the `hash`-function like this:

```
hash('whirlpool', $the_data_to_be_hashed);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it supports a range of algorithms depending on which version you are using. Check out [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php) for a complete list, but version 5.3 supports the whole sha2 family, ripemd, whirlpool, tiger and others.